# Buttons only appearing in Firefox and not in other browsers

Tags: firefox, button, input

I'm currently making improvements to a software made by someone else and I am having trouble figuring out why a pair of buttons that are inside an input field only appears in Firefox and not in any other browsers.

Also I can't seem to find the source code for these buttons.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpGOk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume these buttons appear because the input field type is set to "number". When using this, it's the browser job to manage this type of field and thus may or not use spinning buttons (up/down).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have gotten rid of those buttons by setting it to "textfield".